# Bootstrap Validator summernote field doesn't revalidate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, summernote

I'm using the bootstrap validator plugin to valid my form client side and it seems to fail when revalidating a summernote textarea. It validates the first time, but when the text is updated the validation doesn't update.

Here's the validation (*snipped out other validation fields*)

```
function validateEditor() {
    // Revalidate the content when its value is changed by Summernote
    $('#application-form').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'application'));
};

$('.application-form')
    .bootstrapValidator({
        excluded: [':disabled'],
        fields: {
            application: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Please do not leave this blank.',
                        callback: function(value, validator) {
                            var code = $('[name="application"]').code();
                            // <p><br></p> is code generated by Summernote for empty content
                            return (code !== '' && code !== '<p><br></p>');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Form successfully validated.');


    })
    .find('[name="application"]')
        .summernote({
            height: 400,
            onkeyup: function() {

                validateEditor(); // Revalidate form onkeyup

            },
            onpaste: function() {

                validateEditor(); // Revalidate form on paste

            },

        });
```

Here's the markup (*again snipped from other fields*)

```
<div class="form-group">        

    <textarea name="application"></textarea>

</div>
```

This is a huge issue because if the textarea is left blank the first time, the form can never be resubmitted since the validation doesn't update when the error is fixed by the user.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but with FormValidation.io, which is a very similar plugin.

**Solution** : My textarea had the `required` attribute. I **removed it** and bam, problem solved.

Now, I'm genuinely sorry if this isn't a direct solution to your problem, your code obviously doesn't have the `required` attribute, but I just thought I'd share with other people still, because this was driving me nuts for hours and this was the most relevant post about this problem on here.

That is all.